# MongoDB Motor - Cannot $push into nested array using variables

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update a nested array in my mongodb document, and I cant figure out how to `$push` using variables in such a nested array. The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) say to use the dot notation but I cant use that since I have different `key` and `node_id` against which I need to `$push`

```
for key, value in docs.items():
    print(f'Key: {key} Value: {value}')
    for node_id, timestamp in value.items():
    result = await db[collection].update_one({'user_id': user_id, 'date': date}, {'$push':{"key.node_id": timestamp}}, upsert=True)
return result.modified_count
```

`value` is a nested dictionary inside `docs`. Using the above code just updates the document with `str 'key'` and `'node_id'`. How do I access variables using dot notation in this case?

UPDATE:

This is a sample document that I am trying to build

```
{
  "date": "18/04/2020",
  "user_id": "my_user",
  "standing": [
    { "2": [1582805181, 1582805183] },
    { "3": [1582805181, 1582805183] }
  ],
  "sitting": [
    { "2": [1582805181, 1582805183] },
    { "3": [1582805181, 1582805183] }
  ],
  "walking": [
    { "2": [1582805181, 1582805183] },
    { "3": [1582805181, 1582805183] }
  ]
}
```

Update 2:

`key` will be either one of three sitting, standing, walking. `value` is a nested dictionary in docs whose keys can be 2 or 3 - `node_id` in this case and `timestamp` will be a unix timestamp of 10 digits.

Comment: Please include a sample input document in your post.

Comment: @prasad_ updated with a sample document

Comment: Also, tell what are the values in `"key.node_id"` and `timestamp`. Are you getting any errors when you run the code?

Comment: @prasad_ details added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$push` update operator into a nested array using variables. The variable values are constructed from the provided `key` and the `node_id` values.

The following two variables: (i) `cond_var` is used with the update method's query condition, and (ii) the `updt_var` is used with the update.

```
cond_var = key + "." + node_id
updt_var = key + "." + "$" + "." + node_id

result = collection.update_one( { 'user_id': user_id, 'date': date, cond_var: { '$exists': True  } },  
                                { '$push': { updt_var : timestamp } },
                                upsert=True )
```